Selenium - Powershell - Wait-for-element not working
I am trying to implement an increased wait period for elements.  However, it appears that neither the increased time out 60 seconds, nor the default of 10, are being recognized.  It takes about a second and a half for the site to load, but I immediately receive an error that the first element I am looking for cannot be found.
cls
$workingPath = "D:\Dev\Selenium"
$env:PATH += ";$workingPath"
Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\lib\netstandard2.0\WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\lib\netstandard2.0\WebDriver.Support.dll"

$chromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$chromeOptions.AddArgument('start-maximized')
$chromeOptions.AddArgument('disable-gpu')
$chromeOptions.AddArgument('ignore-certificate-errors')
$chromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($workingPath, $chromeOptions)

[OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait]$wait = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait ($chromeDriver, [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(60))

$SiteUrl = "http://192.168.27.10"
$chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($siteURL)

$username = $ChromeDriver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id('loginUsername-inputEl'))
$wait.Until([System.Func[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]] { param($chromeDriver)Try { $username } Catch { $null } })

As far as I know, the above "should" work.  However, once the site loads, there does not appear to be any wait for the element, and the below error is thrown:
Exception calling "FindElement" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#loginUsername\-inputEl"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.123); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception"
At line:18 char:1
+ $username = $ChromeDriver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id('login ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoSuchElementException

I can confirm that the wait does indeed get adjusted to 60 seconds by running $wait:
$wait

Timeout  PollingInterval  Message
-------  ---------------  -------
00:01:00 00:00:00.5000000 

Maybe I am doing something wrong; I'm not sure.  Any suggestions??

it looks like you are waiting for an element after trying to look for an element (should flip the wait and the username lines)

Your current code doesn't make much sense. You are waiting on the first result of the FindElement() call instead of repeatedly calling FindElement().
I think the FindElement call should be inside the script block called by $wait.Until():
$script:username = $null

# In this Func type, the first type relates to the parameter of the script block
# and the second type relates to its return value.
$null = $wait.Until( [Func[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, Boolean]] { param($chromeDriver)

    try {
        $script:username = $chromeDriver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id('loginUsername-inputEl'))
        $true  # As there was no exception, exit the wait loop
    }
    catch { 
        $false  # Exception occurred, need to wait another time
    } 
})

# For debugging, output the value of the variable after the wait loop has finished
$script:username

Note:

I'm using a script-scoped variable because the script block called by $wait.Until() runs in a new scope and can't directly modify variables in the parent scope (it can only read them, due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping). There are other options like using a reference or using Set-Variable -Scope 1, which you may want to explore.


Hey, this works great!  The only change I had to make was to remove OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement from the System.Func and insert System.Boolean.  This was because:
Exception calling "Until" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot convert value "False" to type "OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'.""
    Otherwise, thank you.  I think my main issue was just not quite understanding the correct way to implement the timeout.  Now I need to increase the scope to the rest of my elements.


Oooof the comments section never formats well, sorry.  Regardless, thanks again

The delegate should be able to access that parent scope defined variable just that it wouldn't be able to update it without the scope modifier.

@SantiagoSquarzon You are absolutely right, thanks!

What the heck is the method to suppress 'True' being written every time?  I tried piping to null but that didn't work.  I assume there is away to stop that from occurring?

@sbagnato Try $null = $wait.Until(.... I believe the function either returns the value from the script block or its own status. Any unassigned return values are implicitly output by PowerShell, which can be a headache at times. By assigning to the fake variable $null, the return value is effectively discarded.

Good call; that did it.
